# Combox Box binding for datagrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox, binding, datagrid

I am creating a grid for displaying report of all delay fetching from database
(DownTime delay having records with field id, starttime, endtime, trigger, SubArea,MajorReason, DetailsReason).

This record is fatched or inserted on basis trigger what I get from PLC it working fine I am able to insert records in Downtime Table.

Now when I display this record in datagrid it displaying Start Time, End Time ,Area( which is fixed as per trigger a single textbox value displayed successfully).

But now the problem is SubArea list which is based on Area selected it should in combo box and should be different per row Area value. Again when Sub Area is selected another list in next column should be with list of all Major Reason which are for this sub Area. Same when Major Reason selected another list of Details Reason for this MajorReason should be displayed in combox box for this MajorReason in next column.

In summary I will have Column heading in Datagrid Start Time,End Time, Area, Sub Area , Major Reason, Detail Reason

where Start time , ENd Time Area will displayed as text block readonly from DownTime Table.

But In column Sub Area will have combo list of all Sub Area(in column heading Sub Area) which belongs to perticular Area( I have table SubArea i.e. id, subarea, area)

Then when Sub Area is selected will have combo list all Major Reason ( in column with heading Major Reason) which belongs to particular  Sub Area( I have table Major Reason with field id,MajorReason,SubArea)

Same when Major Reason selected will have combo list of all Detail Reason ( In column with heading Detail Reason) which belongs to particular Major Reason.

Thanks in advance help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into [DataGridComboBoxColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx)
and for dynamic binding look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970769/wpf-datagrid-dynamically-bind-datagridcomboboxcolumn-based-on-row)